# What is the difference between void function and int *function for returning arrays

Tags: arrays, c, function, return-value, return-type

When dealing with arrays as they are passed by reference is there a difference between function return type like this 2 examples:

```
int *swap (int *arr, int size)
{
    // code
    return arr;
}
// OR
void swap (int *arr, int size)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One is returning the array and one is not. That's the difference.

This feature is used in two ways.

1. For some functions a null pointer indicates that something has happened. Usually an error. In others, a pointer is returned somewhere in the array. `strchr` returns a pointer to the first specified character found.
2. It allows chaining functions, like `foo(bar(swap(arr, size)))`

[Live demo of (1)](https://onlinegdb.com/GvhvSJ9_H) (try to enter C-d)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char buffer[100] = {};

    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) 
        puts("Error");
    else
        puts(buffer);
}
```

[Live demo of (2)](https://onlinegdb.com/C2yAKNKC6)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

```
int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "hello ";
    char str2[] = "world!";
    
    char buffer[100] = {0};
    
    puts(strcat(memcpy(buffer, str1, strlen(str1)), str2));
}
```

Comment: #2 has undefined behavior as `buffer` is not initialized, so the result of the `memcpy` might not be properly null terminated.  Can be fixed by initializing `char buffer[100] = {};` or by using `strcpy` instead of `mempcy`, or by adding 1 to the length to copy the nul terminator.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first function is returning a copy of the pointer that was passed as its first argument.  The second one is not.

Assuming the first function doesn't modify `arr`, there's not much point in returning it.

Comment: But even if the void function didn't return anything. It's still editing the main array. So what is the use of the first function.

Comment: @SherifBeshr Exactly.  There's no point returning anything.

Comment: There is a point. That point is chaining functions.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the first one creates a new array, and returns a pointer to the first element, whereas the second modifies the array in place (so doesn't need to return anything, since `arr`, the location of the array, won't change).

As you say, `arr` isn't the array, it's a reference to it - which basically just tells the function where the array is in memory. The analogy I like to use is telling an employee which filing cabinet to look in. With the `int*` function, the employee makes a new array and then tells you which cabinet they put it in (by `return`ing a pointer to it). With the `void` function, the employee just changes stuff and then puts it back in the same cabinet, so they don't need to tell you anything since you already know where the array is.

Comment: In the question as asked, there's no new array being created.

Comment: @SteveSummit I assumed a new array was being created since otherwise I saw no reason to return the pointer. There are good points in some other answers and comments about chaining functions

Comment: Lots of functions accept a pointer (to an array) as an argument, and return the same pointer, without allocating a new one.  Examples from the standard library are `fgets`, `strcpy`, and `strcat`.